# File importing with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm importing the file, but I can't give the type of the file, how can I solve this problem?

```
import { capitalize } from "utils";

import * as Icons from "./";
type IconType = {
  name: string;
};
const icon = ({ name, ...props }: IconType) => {
  const newName = capitalize(name);
  if (!Icons[newName]) return null;

  const CustomIcon = Icons[newName];
  return <CustomIcon {...props} />;
};

export default icon;
```

[image]

Comment: *"...but I can't give the type of the file..."* What do you mean by "can't"?

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Can you post the contents of **Icons/index.ts**?

Comment: contents of Icons/index.ts = export { default as Heart } from "./Heart";

Answer (score 0):

You can probably *fix* your issue by typing `Icons[newName as keyof Icons]`.

You have a lot of bad practices in your code you should fix, though:

1. You should add a `import * as icons from "./pathToIcons";`. Importing by the index.ts should only happen if importing from outside the same folder;
2. `const icon = (...)` A component should start with capital letter, `const Icon = (...)`;
3. `{ name, ...props }: IconType` This is incoherent, because your type `IconType` only has one attribute `name`, therefore in your case, typescript should infer `props typeof never`. Probably you want something `interface IconProps extends CustomIconProps { name: string }`

Comment: Is it possible for you to write in detail, I tried but it didn't work. I may be using it wrong